# Copying Data from two worksheets into two other worksheets on top of ech other

Tags: excel, vba

In this picture,

[image]

you see what I am trying to achieve and what is actually happening. I have been able to determine that the data is overwriting the data that was placed first. What should be happening is I need to copy data from :

1. MIM Data to MIM QA
2. BCRS Data to BCRS QA
3. MIM Data to BCRS QA (Copied to the next empty row)
4. BCRS Data to MIM QA (Copied to the next empty row)

This is the code I am using. I have tried several variations of this with no luck. I borrowed this code from another worksheet that was doing something similar, meaning, taking new data and adding it to the next empty row.

```
Sub QA_Data_Copy_1603_A()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim March_Swivel As Workbook ' Source Workbook
        Set March_Swivel = Workbooks("Swivel - Master - March 2016.xlsm")
    Dim MIM_Data As Worksheet ' Source Worksheet
        Set MIM_Data = March_Swivel.Sheets("MIM Data")
    Dim BCRS_Data As Worksheet ' Source Worksheet
        Set BCRS_Data = March_Swivel.Sheets("BCRS Data")
    Dim MIM_QA As Worksheet ' Destination Worksheet
        Set MIM_QA = March_Swivel.Sheets("MIM QA")
    Dim BCRS_QA As Worksheet ' Destination Worksheet
        Set BCRS_QA = March_Swivel.Sheets("BCRS QA")

    ' Source Rows

    Dim MLastRow As Long
        MLastRow = MIM_Data.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    Dim BLastRow As Long
        BLastRow = BCRS_Data.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

    ' Destination Rows

    Dim MRow As Long
        MRow = MIM_QA.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
    Dim BRow As Long
        BRow = BCRS_QA.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row


        MIM_Data.Range("A2:J" & MLastRow).Copy Destination:=MIM_QA.Range("A" & MRow + 1)
        BCRS_Data.Range("A2:J" & BLastRow).Copy Destination:=BCRS_QA.Range("A" & BRow + 1)
        MIM_Data.Range("A2:J" & MLastRow).Copy Destination:=BCRS_QA.Range("A" & BRow + 1)
        BCRS_Data.Range("A2:J" & BLastRow).Copy Destination:=MIM_QA.Range("A" & MRow + 1)

    Worksheets("BCRS Data").Columns("A:J").AutoFit
    Worksheets("MIM Data").Columns("A:J").AutoFit
    Worksheets("BCRS QA").Columns("A:J").AutoFit
    Worksheets("MIM QA").Columns("A:J").AutoFit

    Call QA_Color_Text

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to recalculate your last row before moving data the second time.

Some modifications in the code below due to how I set up my test, but you can see the recalculations ...

```
Option Explicit

Sub QA_Data_Copy_1603_A()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'    Dim March_Swivel As Workbook ' Source Workbook
'        Set March_Swivel = Workbooks("Swivel - Master - March 2016.xlsm")
    Dim MIM_Data As Worksheet ' Source Worksheet
        Set MIM_Data = Sheets("MIMData")
    Dim BCRS_Data As Worksheet ' Source Worksheet
        Set BCRS_Data = Sheets("BCRSData")
    Dim MIM_QA As Worksheet ' Destination Worksheet
        Set MIM_QA = Sheets("MIMQA")
    Dim BCRS_QA As Worksheet ' Destination Worksheet
        Set BCRS_QA = Sheets("BCRSQA")

    ' Source Rows

    Dim MIMDataLRow As Long
        MIMDataLRow = MIM_Data.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim BCRSDataLRow As Long
        BCRSDataLRow = BCRS_Data.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    ' Destination Rows

    Dim MIMQALRow As Long
        MIMQALRow = MIM_QA.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim BCRSQALRow As Long
        BCRSQALRow = BCRS_QA.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row


        MIM_Data.Range("A2:J" & MIMDataLRow).Copy Destination:=MIM_QA.Range("A" & MIMQALRow + 1)
        MIMQALRow = MIM_QA.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        BCRS_Data.Range("A2:J" & BCRSDataLRow).Copy Destination:=MIM_QA.Range("A" & MIMQALRow + 1)

        BCRS_Data.Range("A2:J" & BCRSDataLRow).Copy Destination:=BCRS_QA.Range("A" & BCRSQALRow + 1)
        BCRSQALRow = BCRS_QA.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        MIM_Data.Range("A2:J" & MIMDataLRow).Copy Destination:=BCRS_QA.Range("A" & BCRSQALRow + 1)

'    Worksheets("BCRS Data").Columns("A:J").AutoFit
'    Worksheets("MIM Data").Columns("A:J").AutoFit
'    Worksheets("BCRS QA").Columns("A:J").AutoFit
'    Worksheets("MIM QA").Columns("A:J").AutoFit

'    Call QA_Color_Text

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
'    Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you @OldUgly Worked perfectly.